# Error compile bitcoin mac OS

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, mac, bitcoin-qt-setup

I have straggle to compile bitcoin core on mac OS machine. it has an error as the following:

```
/usr/local/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:667:65: error: expected '>'
         typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T> && std::is_arithmetic_v<U> &&
                                                                ^
/usr/local/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:667:65: error: expected ',' or '>' in
      template-parameter-list
/usr/local/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:668:66: error: expected unqualified-id
                                     std::is_floating_point_v<T> == std::is_floating_po...
                                                                 ^
/usr/local/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:679:35: error: no type named 'Promoted' in namespace
      'QTypeTraits::detail'
using Promoted = typename detail::Promoted<T, U>::type;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:679:43: error: expected ';' after alias declaration
using Promoted = typename detail::Promoted<T, U>::type;
                                          ^
                                          ;
/usr/local/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:691:31: error: no template named 'Promoted' in namespace
      'QTypeTraits'
constexpr inline QTypeTraits::Promoted<T, U> qMin(const T &a, const U &b)
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/usr/local/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:693:28: error: no template named 'Promoted' in namespace
      'QTypeTraits'
    using P = QTypeTraits::Promoted<T, U>;
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/usr/local/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:694:5: error: unknown type name 'P'
    P _a = a;
    ^
/usr/local/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:695:5: error: unknown type name 'P'
    P _b = b;
    ^
/usr/local/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:699:31: error: no template named 'Promoted' in namespace
      'QTypeTraits'
constexpr inline QTypeTraits::Promoted<T, U> qMax(const T &a, const U &b)
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/usr/local/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:701:28: error: no template named 'Promoted' in namespace
      'QTypeTraits'
    using P = QTypeTraits::Promoted<T, U>;
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/usr/local/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:702:5: error: unknown type name 'P'
    P _a = a;
    ^
/usr/local/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:703:5: error: unknown type name 'P'
    P _b = b;
    ^
/usr/local/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:707:31: error: no template named 'Promoted' in namespace
      'QTypeTraits'
constexpr inline QTypeTraits::Promoted<T, U> qBound(const T &min, const U &val, const T &max)
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/usr/local/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:710:31: error: no template named 'Promoted' in namespace
      'QTypeTraits'
constexpr inline QTypeTraits::Promoted<T, U> qBound(const T &min, const T &val, const U &max)
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/usr/local/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:713:31: error: no template named 'Promoted' in namespace
      'QTypeTraits'
constexpr inline QTypeTraits::Promoted<T, U> qBound(const U &min, const T &val, const T &max)
```

Please advise.

i used command brew install qt5

Comment: How did you install Qt? what's its version?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, seems like the problem is that I had both qt5 and qt6 installed, and it used qt6. Try running:

```
brew uninstall qt
brew install qt5
```